# I'm don't understand what the colon does in str.format

Tags: python

https://coderbyte.com/information/Division%20Stringified

> Have the function DivisionStringified(num1,num2) take both parameters
>   being passed, divide num1 by num2, and return the result as a string
>   with properly formatted commas. If an answer is only 3 digits long,
>   return the number with no commas (ie. 2 / 3 should output "1"). For
>   example: if num1 is 123456789 and num2 is 10000 the output should be
>   "12,346".

This is the top user's solution, not mine:

```
def DivisionStringified(num1, num2): 
    return '{:,}'.format((num1 + (num2 / 2)) / num2)
```

What does `'{:,}'.format` do? I have no idea how that would place commas in the correct positions in a large number.

Comment: I love the way you mentioned on the top "THIS IS NOT HOMEWORK" :)

Comment: See the section of the Python documentation on [format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings). (It's a pretty dense read; don't expect to absorb all of it immediately, but it'll be important to learn to read stuff like that and pick out the parts that are relevant to you.)

Comment: if you only need to apply string formatting to one thing just use the [`format` builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) `return format( (num1+(num2/2))/num2, ',')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) says that:

> The ',' option signals the use of a comma for a thousands separator. For a locale aware separator, use the 'n' integer presentation type instead.

So we can see that is what the `,` is doing in the format string.

As for the `:`, the *general* format of a format string is something like:

```
{what:format_spec}
```

Both parts are optional -- The default format spec simply `!s` (which means format this using the `str` builtin).  And if the "what" part isn't specified, then python just fills in the position of the appropriate positional argument.  In this case, the `:` is necessary so that the format parser can pick up the format_spec part.